# Python Newrelic agent no data

Tags: python, web.py, newrelic

im trying to install newrelic python agent on my server but i just cant. I did what is said here [newrelic](https://rpm.newrelic.com/applications/setup#) and i started the server like this:

```
NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE=newrelic.ini newrelic-admin run-program nohup python code.py 80 &
```

but it doest work.I also tryed to add

```
import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize('newrelic.ini')
```

on my code.py file which is where i start the web app but then if i do

```
nohup python code.py 80 &
```

the web app code.py doest work

update::
I dont know how but i think it started just for like 20 sec. I closed the root terminal and it stoped i think becasue of that.
now it says in newrelic.com:

```
No data reporting for this application - troubleshoot
```

can someone help me? pd: sorry for my english

Comment: Which web framework and WSGI server are you using?

When you were using the `newrelic.agent.initailize` call, it sounds like it started working for 20 seconds or so before you closed your terminal. Is that right? Do you have a link to where it reported in New Relic (rpm.newrelic.com link)?

Comment: yes, [gyazo](http://gyazo.com/3feeed92d1ed8ef74b7830fddffe7725)

Comment: That shows only the [Python Agent Test](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/python-agent/installation-configuration/testing-python-agent#connectivity-test) rather than your actual application reporting data. So, it looks like your actual application itself hasn't reported data yet. Is there traffic on your application? Which web framework and WSGI server are you using?

Comment: correct. The test is always working but not the aplication. Im using web.py framwork. Please see also this post of mine [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28549979/python-agent-newrelic-installation)

Answer (score 1):

This might be late, but I ran into a similar issue as well. Instead of using `newrelic.ini` I was able to get this working using environment variables instead of using the `newrelic.ini` file.

```py
import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize()
```

Then, set environment variables for the `NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME` and `NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY` before running your python application.

Bash:

```sh
export NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME="Python App"
export NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXNRAL"
python3 web.py
```