# Python agent newrelic installation

Tags: python, newrelic

im trying to install python agent of newrelic on my webapp but i just cant. im using a file named code.py to start my app.
I add at the begging:

```
import newrelic.agent
newrelic.agent.initialize('newrelic.ini')
```

and i also tryed:

```
 import newrelic.agent
 newrelic.agent.initialize('/root/web/newrelic.ini')
```

but i get some error like

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "code.py", line 2, in <module>
import newrelic.agent
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/newrelic-        2.44.0.36/newrelic/agent.py", line 1, in <module>
 from .config import initialize, extra_settings
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/newrelic-2.44.0.36/newrelic/config.py", line 34, in <module>
  import newrelic.console
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/newrelic-2.44.0.36/newrelic/console.py", line 5, in <module>
  import code
File "/root/web/code.py", line 3, in <module>
 newrelic.agent.initialize('newrelic.ini')
 AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'agent'
```

can someone help?? thanks

Comment: Don't screenshot text.  Copy and paste the error into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rename your script to something other than `code.py`. (And, also delete `code.pyc`.) The problem is your script name conflicts with a [standard Python module called code](https://docs.python.org/2/library/code.html), so when the agent tries to `import code`, it winds up importing your script, not the standard module.

See this description of the "name shadowing trap" for more details: http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap